# Command line: "-" converted to "û"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm running this command in a .bat or .cmd file to launch an ftp script:

```
ftp –v –i –s:test_script.txt
```

Command window converts it to this:

```
ftp ûv ûi ûs:test_script.txt
```

And thus it does not work.

Note: if I manually run the above command from a cmd window, it works fine. Only fails when I launch it as a .bat or .cmd file.

Need help preventing the conversion. Thanks.

Comment: To what file format are you saving the .bat file (ANSI, UTF-8, UCS-2 LE/BE)?  Is the command line in `/a` ASCII or `/u` Unicode mode?  What is the code page set? enter the command `chcp`.

Comment: .bat file is ANSI. Active code page: 437. command line is running ASCII.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dashes you have in the command you've provided are ASCII 150, but the dashes used in switches to commands are ASCII 45.  I would guess you have copy/pasted this command from a Word doc or email where the editor "helpfully" changed the dashes to em-dashes.

If you copy/paste your command from this question into a cmd window, it won't run properly because of the wrong dashes.  Are you retyping it at the command line, perhaps, rather than copy/pasting?

Regardless, the solution is to retype the dashes in your batch file.