# Topic creation error Kafka on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-kafka

After multiple re-tries and changing the bat files, I have finally succeeded in running Kafka and Zookeeper in Windows 7. This is a 32-bit machine running Java 7. Unfortunately though, I am not able to create a topic. I tried using the tutorial here: http://janschulte.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/apache-kafka-0-8-on-windows/

I executed the command:

C:\Cambria\kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0>bin\kafka-create-topic.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica 1 --partition 1 --topic topic

and end up with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: 'û' is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:89)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.validateOptionCharacters(OptionParser.java:586)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionCluster(OptionParser.java:511)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionToken(OptionParser.java:506)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:59)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:433)
    at kafka.admin.CreateTopicCommand$.main(CreateTopicCommand.scala:56)
    at kafka.admin.CreateTopicCommand.main(CreateTopicCommand.scala)
```

All the classpath entries are proper and the requisite JAR files are also present. Am not sure what the issue is. Can someone help me on this?

P.S: I tried this with Cygwin and am encountering the Class Not Found error although the classpath is being properly set.

Comment: Pretty sure you're running into this issue:
[Hyphen converted to u][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663395/command-line-converted-to-u

Comment: Yes, I found that out a later point. It has been resolved now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 33):

For people who just started to play with kafka and encountered this problem (but on Unix machine), this is due to the outdated tutorial you are following.

In [the latest version](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart), you have to use

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

to create topic.

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this answer. Exactly what the problem was. Outdated documentation.

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: I got the outdated tutorial here: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart in case anyone using that tutorial wants to know if Salvador's solution worked. It definitely worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

run bin\kafka-create-topic.bat to see available options 
then for example you will see broker-list and all required parameters.